# How to get each different value of form ruining in loop with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify

I have products in loop on collection page and I want to get each product value with jQuery and ajax but code I have, only getting first product value whenever we click on any product's add to cart button, is only showing of first product, below is my code:

```
function addItem(form_id) {
  var postData = $('#'+form_id).serialize();
  alert(postData);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
   dataType: 'json',
  data: $('#'+form_id).serialize(),
  success: addToCartOk,
  error: addToCartFail
});
```

}

Here I am checking: https://soft-theme.myshopify.com/collections/all its only getting id=27733468427 which ever button I click

Anyone can help me on this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several forms with the same ID. This is not allowed in HTML DOM: each `id="..."` attribute should be unique, you can’t use several forms with the same `id="add-to-cart"`. When browser encounters several objects with the same `id`, it ignores other objects with this `id`, because `id`’s should be unique.

You can to use `class="add-to-cart"` instead.

(Also, remove the `id="add"` from your add buttons, it's also a duplicate `id`. You can use class instead.)

Also, you don't really need to pass an ID in your code. You can get the form wrapping the element using `this`, which refers to the button clicked (however, it needs to be wrapped with a `$` to convert the DOM object into the jQuery object):

So, you can use this in your forms:

```
<form method="post" action="/cart/add" class="add-to-cart">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="27733468427" class="ppp" />
  <input type="submit" name="add"
         value="Add to Cart"
         onclick="addItem(this); return false;"/>
</form>
```

This is a reference to the `<input type="submit" ... />` element. So, you can just get the form wrapping this element by using `.closest`, like this:

```
function addItem(button) {
  var $button = $(button);
  var $form = $button.closest('form');
  var postData = $form.serialize();
  alert(postData);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
   dataType: 'json',
  data: $form.serialize(),
  success: addToCartOk,
  error: addToCartFail
});
```

This is not the recommended way of doing things, though. `onclick="..."` is a deprecated way of doing things, because you are mixing JavaScript with HTML. Instead, it's recommended to remove `onclick="..."` alltogether and bind the event callback in a `<script>` code. To do this, just remove the `onclick` in your forms:

```
<form method="post" action="/cart/add" class="add-to-cart">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="27733468427" class="ppp" />
  <input type="submit" name="add"
         value="Add to Cart"/>
</form>
```

And bind the method using class `add-to-cart` (make sure you’ve made it into the class, otherwise my code won’t work):

```
$(function() {
  $("form.add-to-cart").submit(function () {
    var $form = $(this);
    var postData = $form.serialize();
    alert(postData);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/cart/add.js',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $form.serialize(),
      success: addToCartOk,
      error: addToCartFail
    });
    return false;
});
```

The code above does the following:

- The `$(function() { ... });` around the code makes sure that the code is only run when all the elements are loaded.
- `$("form.add-to-cart")` finds all the forms with `class="add-to-cart"`
- `$("form.add-to-cart").submit(function () { ... });` adds a callback function. This function will be called each time any form with `class="add-to-cart"` is submited.

This is the recommended alternative to `onclick`.

**Update:** the first version of my code had a bug: since `$("form.add-to-cart").submit` is attached to the form, and not to the button, we should use `$(this)` to refer to the form. We don’t need `closest` in the second version of the code.

Comment: Its not working, I have added same code you have provided also by adding class add-to-cart in form

Comment: Also, if my code triggered an error, please send it to me and I’ll fix it. Currently you’re not using my code, and I don’t have the same environment to test my code, so I can’t comment about why it wasn’t working

Comment: Use addItem(this) in onclick, and then function addItem(button) { var postData = $(button).closest('.add-to-cart').serialize();

Comment: Your current code searches for $('.add-to-cart'), which means it will search for ALL the forms, not for the form user clicked

Comment: Can I send you the login details of back end of store where code runing, so you can check in details?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, I don’t want to take responsibility for your site by having the login details. Maybe you could copy my code to your page again, so that I can see the error displayed on your test page?

Comment: Currently your page has missing ' in var $form = $(this).closest('.add-to-cart'); , it has var $form = $(this).closest('.add-to-cart);

Comment: I'm glad to hear this! :)

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/each/

You want to use each attribute of jquery. I hope this will help you.